# API Platform disable redirect to login

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com, symfony-security

I am developing a website using Symfony 4 and API Platform. My user resource is protected by standard Symfony security (`"security": "is_granted('ROLE_USER')"`):

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
* @ApiResource(
*     collectionOperations={
*         "get_user_profile": {
*             "method": "GET",
*             "path": "/users/profile",
*             "controller": GetUserProfile::class,
*             "pagination_enabled": false,
*             "openapi_context": {"summary": "Retrieves the current User's profile."},
*             "security": "is_granted('ROLE_USER')"
*         },
*     },
*     itemOperations={},
*     normalizationContext={"groups": {"read"}},
* )
*/
class User implements UserInterface
{
}
```

The problem is that if I try to access this API the response is a **redirect** to the login page.
How can I **disable the redirect** and leave the response as a 401?

The redirect is really useful for website users but API users should not receive an HTML response.

This is my security.yml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|img|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: lazy
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                # where to redirect after logout
                # target: app_any_route

            remember_me:
                secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path:     /

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

**SOLUTION:** I needed to override the `start` method with something like this:

```
/**
 * Override to control what happens when the user hits a secure page
 * but isn't logged in yet.
 *
 * @return RedirectResponse
 */
public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
{
    /** @var string */
    $format = $request->getRequestFormat();

    // API request
    if (false !== strpos($format, 'json')) {
        throw new HttpException(Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    $url = $this->getLoginUrl();

    return new RedirectResponse($url);
}
```

Comment: @yivi I added all the details about request, response and JSON. Please note that I am making the request using the API Platform tool.

Comment: Yes, this is the signature: `class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator implements PasswordAuthenticatedInterface`. I created it using Symfony MakerBundle

Comment: Ok, that's your problem. Removed the request/response headers since were not actually needed to resolve the issue in the end. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have only one guard authenticator, and that authenticator is  `LoginFormAuthenticator`, which extends on `AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator`.

This abstract class is handy, but it's thought out to be used for regular web clients, not for API flows.

If you check it's `start()` method you'll find [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/59126e0f9c20f5af74cb851c8d6a6399cd286deb/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Guard/Authenticator/AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator.php#L96):

```
    /**
     * Override to control what happens when the user hits a secure page
     * but isn't logged in yet.
     *
     * @return RedirectResponse
     */
    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
        $url = $this->getLoginUrl();
        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }
```

So any time an authenticated request hits, it gets this redirect response.

Your options are:

#### Cheap and easy:

Override `start()` on `LoginFormAuthenticator` so it returns something like:

```
return new JsonReponse(
    ['status' => 'KO', 'message' => 'Unauthorized'],
    Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED]
);
```

This would will return a JSON with 401 an all unauthorized requests. But "regular" web requests would not get redirected to the login form. Which is not ideal.

#### Slightly better:

Check on `start()` if the request has an `application/*` content-type, and return a 401 on those, but redirect the rest to the login form.

#### What you should actually do down the road:

The API URLs should be protected by a different guard authenticator than regular web paths. Reserve the login-form for traffic not related to the API. The Api-Platform package [has built-in support for JWT authentication](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/jwt/). Just use that, it is very easy to implement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very informative! Unfortunately this is my first SF 4 project and I always used FOSRest manually. I would like to go with the third option but my scenario is a HTML / JavaScript client game **inside** a protected page so there is not an API login. Can I actually use your third option in this scenario?

Comment: Everything is possible, but the devil lies in the details. The specifics would be implementation-dependant. Start with the easy approach, and implement the latter when you are more confident in your abilities and know a bit more about how authentication is performed in Symfony.